# Handling and Displaying Parse SDK log messages

Tags: ios, logging, error-handling, parse-platform

Parse logs following messages during networking connection fails,

- Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.917510 seconds.
- Network connection failed. Making attempt 3 after sleeping for 3.835019 seconds.
- Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 7.670039 seconds.
- Network connection failed. Making attempt 5 after sleeping for 15.340078 seconds.

How to listen these log messages, so that I can display in my UIAlertView.

Comment: As of now, parse.com doesn't has exposed API to handle this. They mentioned that will include in feature request.